# Passing variable over class to included file

Tags: php

I included a file over a **template.class.php**:

```
    class template {
        function loadtemplate() { 
            include_once("file.tpl");
        }
    }
```

after that I created a new object of the class using (in **index.php**):

```
$template = new template();
```

then I executed the method, to include the file (in **index.php**):

```
<?php $template->loadtemplate(); ?>
```

Now I want to execute a function defined in **index.php** in my **file.tpl**

error: Undefined variable: var.
How can I pass the variable? If I include the file directly in index.php without using the method, the variable is being passed.

Answer (score 1):

found out a solution by myself:

```
function loadtemplate($var) {...}
```

in **index.php**

```
<?php $template->loadtemplate($var); ?>
```